# Dynamic item height with equal spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What I want to achieve is a layout like this.

[image]

Inside to box there will be other content like image, text, button and so on. what I want is make the box sizing dynamic so that it's it takes the height of it's content. The first option came to my mind is use a collection view flow layout.

After some trial and error I end up with this layout.

[image]

My Problem is the inter item spacing I want them to be equal, is there any way to achieve this?
Any suggestion I greatly appreciated.

What I have tried so far.

```swift
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.configure(title: data[indexPath.row].title)
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let spacing: CGFloat = 10
        let numberOfItemsPerRow:CGFloat = 2
        let spacingBetweenCells:CGFloat = 10
        
        let totalSpacing = (2 * spacing) + ((numberOfItemsPerRow - 1) * spacingBetweenCells)
        
        
        let approximateWidthOfContent = view.frame.width - 32
        let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfContent, height: 1000)
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: data[indexPath.row].title).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
        
        if let collection = self.collectionView{
            let width = (collection.bounds.width - totalSpacing)/numberOfItemsPerRow
            return CGSize(width: width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 50)
        }else{
            return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are similar questions but I could not find any which meets my requirement.

Comment: Can you post some code? would be easier to help

Comment: Sure. I will update the question with some sample code.

Comment: You need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout `and create your own Custom Layout logic.

Comment: @Larme Can you please guide me where I can find some tutorials on making some custom layout?

Comment: Plenty of tutorials. There even might have one existing in Github or else with the result you want. But that mean some search ("UICollectionViewLayout Custom" on Google?) from you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and give my feedback later.

Answer (score 0):

After following a tutorial from `raywenderlich` I finally managed to achieve the layout I wanted, Thanks people who have helped me suggesting with important clues.

What I achieved

[image]

The link for the Instructions I have followed is [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest).

Comment: I have another challenge, what if data are dynamic and loading from network when user scrolls.

Comment: Got it, I just had to remote the empty check of the cache, and calculate size everytime.